# Ubuntu 20.04. How do I turn on the keyboard backlight of my 2010 model Acer Aspire 5745?

Tags: keyboard, acer, backlight, aspire, keyboard-backlight

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have an old Acer Aspire 5745-7247 I purchased back in 2010. I looked at the Ubuntu keyboard shortcut options in the keyboard settings, and keyboard backlight isn't listed there. I used to use Fn + spacebar. I have also tried Fn + ScrLk, but no luck. There seems to be no commands or shortcut for this at all. Please help as I really miss having a backlit keyboard.